# which is the most optimal and correct way to drawing many different dynamic 3D models (they are animated and change every frame)

Tags: opengl, 3d, models, vbo

I need to know how I can render many different 3D models, which change their geometry to each frame (are animated models), don't repeat models and textures.

I carry all models and for each created an "object" model class.

What is the most optimal way to render them?

1. To use 1 VBO for each 3D model
2. To use a single VBO for all models (to be all different, I do not see this option possible)

I work with OpenGL 3.x or higher, C++ on Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL; DR - there's no silver bullet when it comes to rendering performance

Why is that? That depends on the complicated process that gets your data, converts it, pushes it to GPU and then makes pixels on the screen flicker. So, instead of "one best way", a few of guideliness appeared that might usually improve the performance.

- Keep all the necessary data on the GPU <sub>(because the closer to the screen, the shorter way electrons have to go `:)`)</sub>
- Send as little data to GPU *between frames* as possible
- Don't sync needlessly between CPU and GPU <sub>(that's like trying to run two high speed trains on parallel tracks, but insisting on slowing them down to the point where you can pass something through the window every once in a while)</sub>,

Now, it's obvious that if you want to have a model that will change, you *can't* have the cake and eat it. You have to made tradeoffs. Simply put, dynamic objects will never render as fast as static ones. So, what should you do?

- Hint GPU about the data usage (`GL_STREAM_DRAW` or `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW`) - that should guarantee optimal memory arrangement.
- Don't use interleaved buffers to mix static vertex attributes with dynamic ones - if you divide the memory, you can batch-update the geometry leaving texture coordinates intact, for example.
- Try to do as much as you can purely on the GPU - with compute shaders and transform feedback, it might well be possible to store whole animation data as a buffer itself and calculate it on GPU, avoiding expensive syncs.

And last but not least, **always carefully measure the impact of your change on performance**. Going blindly won't help. Measure accurately and *thoroughly* (even stuff like shader compilation time might matter sometimes!). Then, even if you go by trial-and-error, there's a hope you'll get somewhere.

---

And to address one of your points in particular; whether it's one large VBO and a few smaller ones doesn't really matter, but a huge one might have problems in fitting in memory. You can still update parts of it, and what matters most is the memory arrangement *inside* of it.

Comment: thanks for the reply, perhaps im not expressed correctly and my questions sound "more general"


for static geometrY I use one large vbo (vertex buffer object) and obtain perfect drawing (performance), but can not find a way
I dont know how do the same with dynamic geometry as a 3d model Animated (changing every frame).

Comment: speaking in terms of OpenGL, i actually use one vbo for each 3D model in the world, and then one render function with:


//indexed drawing
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m_totalVertex, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);


but I think that is not the best or correct way to do this... So I ask, is there any way to render many animated 3D models (differents), using less vbo'S or other technique?
maybe there's another way to resolve the problem, that my lack of experience on this topic can not see, so I come to you,thank you very much.